# .htaccess redirect starts with a % (percent) symbol

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a few external URI's pointing to my site that looks like this:

http://www.example.com/%E2%80%8E

The goal is to redirect this (and any other ASCII encoded character) to the homepage.

I've tried the next options:

```
RewriteRule ^%(.*) http://www.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^\%(.*) http://www.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^â(.*) http://www.example.com [NC]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this redirect rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^\xE2\x80\x8E / [R=302,L]
```

`\xE2\x80\x8E` will match `/%E2%80%8E` URI.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you're trying to catch those, since that character is U+2005. Anywho, if your PCRE library has been built with Unicode support then you can just find either that character specifically with `\x{2005}`, or any Unicode space with `\p{Zs}`. See [`pcre2unicode`](http://pcre.org/current/doc/html/pcre2unicode.html) and [`pcre2syntax`](http://pcre.org/current/doc/html/pcre2syntax.html) for details.

Answer (score 0):

You can also match the encoded characters with a recipe like this (sometiems used to avoid weird mod_rewrite re-encoding behavior)

(the first \w+ is the method)

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^\w+ /%E2%80%8E
RewriteRule ^ / [R=302,L]
```